# Outputting a string using the Curly Braces construct - PHP

Tags: php, string

When i do either of the two sets of code below i get an parse error and the resulting output doesn't show.

Surely there is a way of assigning a value to a variable, creating another variable to output the string, and then echo the variable (using the curly braces{} syntax)?

First Example

```
$name = "Jim ";
$show = echo "{$name}is my name";
echo $show;
```

Second Example

```
$name = "Jim ";
$show = echo "{$name}is my name";
```

Neither of the above work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your setting a variable equal to echo:

$show = `echo`"{$name}is my name";

This should work:

```
$name = "Jim ";
$show = "{$name}is my name";
echo $show;
```

Check here for a working example:

https://ideone.com/ZWDArz